# What state do you get applying the pauli Y gate to $|\pm\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises, pauli-gates

I know it's a basic question but what state gives when you apply pauli $Y$ gate over states $+$ and $-$?

If I apply $Y|+i⟩ = |+i⟩$ or $Y|0⟩ = i|1⟩$, but I don't understand what do you get when you do $Y|+⟩$ or $Y|-⟩$

Answer (score 0):

Lets just compute everything explicitely.

$Y = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & -i\\
i & 0\\
\end{array}\right)$

$\left|+ \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1\\
1\\
\end{array}\right)\, , \, \left|- \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1\\
-1\\
\end{array}\right) $

Now,

$
Y\left|+ \right\rangle = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & -i\\
i & 0\\
\end{array}\right) \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1\\
1\\
\end{array}\right)$

$Y\left|+ \right\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-i\\
i\\
\end{array}\right)$

$Y\left|+ \right\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-i\\
i\\
\end{array}\right)$

$Y\left|+ \right\rangle =\frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
1\\
-1\\
\end{array}\right)$

**$Y\left|+ \right\rangle = -i \left|-\right\rangle$**

Similarly, you can perform matrix-vector multiplication for $Y\left|-\right\rangle$.